# Copy Program Files folder to another volume

Tags: windows, file-transfer, robocopy, files-folders, multi-volume

I want to copy `C:\Program Files` to `D:\Programs` and place a junction instead.

If I run `robocopy "C:\Program Files" D:\Programs /e /copyall /sj /secfix` from *WRE* or any other external environment everything gets copied but Windows becomes corrupted (for instance I can't open any *UWP apps*).

I tried to robocopy to another folder on the same drive but the problem persists, so the issue lies in the copying procedure itself and not into the change of partition.

I fear there is a problem with permissions, since if I just rename the `C:\Program Files` folder to something else and place a junction to it everything works fine.

How can I make an exact copy of everything inside `C:\Program Files`?

Comment: One problem you will face is the fact you should not, specifically, be able to move the WindowsApps directory without actually breaking UWP applications.  Since that directory exists within Program Files, however, you should be able to create a folder on your desired drive and simply install applications to that directory. I just typically just change the drive letter at the installation of programs and it works fine.

Comment: If your goal is space savings, there's other directories that can more more easily. I've done folder redirects for space savings in Windows for a long time, and as I recall, it's never worked for Program Files without severe consequences, intended or not.

Comment: @Ramhound it just seemed more neat to me having everything in one place. Isn't there any way I can make the copy work?

Comment: @music2myear thank you for sharing. It is just frustrating that I can't understand goes wrong in the copying process

Comment: @PellegattaSimone - You don’t have permissions to the WindowsApps folder contained within Program Files.

Comment: @Ramhound not even from an external environment such as wre?

Comment: Also, C:\Program Files\Common is very sensitive and should not be copied/moved either.

Comment: Permissions on NTFS are not at the OS level, but at the storage level. Simply being outside the OS doesn't not magically open full access to the contents of the drive. I cannot speak to whether or not there are tools that can read NTFS and ignore permissions. I would guess it is not a common feature for NTFS-reading tools, and WinRE, at least, lacks that capability.

Comment: Also, you have now indicated this is an X-Y problem: You have a root problem (frequent resets that you'd like to simplify the recovery process from) to which you have assumed a specific solution (moving Program Files). As John has noted this is not a valid solution. Programs don't only exist in this folder, but have legitimate items stored elsewhere in the system that they require in order to function.

Comment: As this question is now into the weeds with your X-Y issue, I suggest marking John's answer as correct, because it is the correct information, whether you want it to be or not, and begin researching how best to simplify the restore process are a computer reset. This could be as simple as taking backups in a "known good" system state prior to making the changes that eventually necessitate the reset, or it may be a more involved process if that is not an option. If you come upon something you cannot solve continuing along that path, bring THAT question here for further counsel.

Answer (score 1):

This would be generally dangerous to do and I suggest you do not move it.

Windows expects Program Files to be on drive C for its many installs.

As you have seen, there are permission issues from tying to move it.

It's size is less than 10 GB on my machines, so I suggest finding neutral files (My Documents) to move. This can be moved safely.

Comment: It's not a space problem: since I often need to reset the computer, I need a way to avoid having to reinstall all the programs even in the absence of backups. Furthermore, the fact that I can edit the %ProgramFiles% path at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` means that it is supported by Windows

Comment: I often need to reset the computer, I need a way to avoid having to reinstall all the programs even in the absence of backups.    ......    Copying Program Folders will not help with this. Some install parts are in the registry and some are in the Users folders.  This is not a good backup avoidance plan. Work up proper backups instead.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no, you can not move "Program Files" to another drive on installed Windows.

There is a way to do this, but can be done only during installation of windows, and it's not really an easy feat since it still requires quite a bit of modding of answer file and registry keys.

And to brake the barrier for rest of folders(and ideas), in essence you can have each and every folder, that is currently in your C drive, in their own drive and have C drive empty totally, but this can never be achieved on installed Windows.

Comment: Could you describe me or link a tutorial on how to achieve this?

Comment: I cant find the tutorials that I used for guidance(was some time ago), but one of guides you can find at; Method 1: Migrate program files to another drive using Registry Editor(https://www.ubackup.com/backup-restore/move-program-files-to-another-drive-windows-10.html) ...and you might use this page (https://www.codium.com.au/blog/moving-users-program-files-in-vista) to get idea what all you must change in reg. In any case to that on as clean Windows as possible, then install your apps, also keep in mind that most apps by default will install to C(not %systemdrive%) and VSs,ADKs must be on C:\

Comment: I was going to accept your answer, but I tried both tutorial and they do not work since they use robocopy which breaks WindowsApps as explained in my question. Is there any alternative way to move files?

Comment: You need clean install of Windows, make D:,use LiveOS then robocopy program files, then edit hive for installed Windows(regedit) by editing every single string/key that mentions "C:/program " and replace it with your "new" program files folder path, and then proceed with OS as usual. Dont forget %sysVariables%. Editing already installed windows that has ton of apps, is next to impossible. You cant move any system folder/file while running on that system, its locked/used.To do any of it, use liveOS. CleanWin=less reg path changes. This is advanced change and itll faill till you get paths right.

Comment: I have already done everything else... The problem lies within robocopy, which corrupts WindowsApps folder

Comment: I'll try to find time and test that, can you just say what windows you are using so i can replicate your surrounding?

Comment: I'm using Windows 11 Home. By the way I guess that the problem has something to do with file encryption inside the folder